# Create SQL DataWarehouse using python

Tags: python, azure, data-warehouse

I need to create a Azure SQL Data Warehouse using python. I could not find any documentation for this. I was able to create the resource group and SQL server using python.

Create resource group:

```
def create_resource():
    # Create Resource group
    print('Create Resource Group')
    print_item(client.resource_groups.create_or_update(group_name, resource_group_params))
```

Create sql server :

```
def create_sql_server():
    # Create SQL Instances
    print('Create SQL Instances')
    sql_client.servers.create_or_update(
        group_name,
        server_name,
        {
            'location': region,
            'version': '12.0',  # Required for create
            'administrator_login': 'ttt',  # Required for create
            'administrator_login_password': 'ttt'  # Required for create
        }
    )
```

Comment: can you provide us with some code that you tried with?

Comment: updated the initial question

Comment: I was able to do this using azure rest api.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/createorupdate#creates_a_data_warehouse_by_specifying_service_objective_name.

Comment: Hi! Please consider posting your solution as an answer so people can upvote it and you can mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using a Rest API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/createorupdate#creates_a_data_warehouse_by_specifying_service_objective_name

```
def create_dwh():
    # Create sql data warehouse
    print('Create sql data warehouse')
    # this will return a azure api token
    token=TokenMgt.get_token()
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': token}
    # parameters 
    # subscription_id : azure subscription id
    # group_name : azure resource group
    # server_name : SQL server name
    # dwh_name : data warehouse db name
    api_url = dwh_end_point.format(subscription_id, group_name, server_name, dwh_name)
    print(api_url)
    data = {
            "location": "westus",
            "sku": {
                "name": "DW100c"
            }
        }
    print(data)
    query_params = {'api-version': '2017-10-01-preview'}
    response = requests.put(url = api_url, params = query_params, json = data, headers = headers)
    response_data = response.json()
    print(response_data)
```